# Getting [Gmail] All Mail from different languages

Tags: gmail, imap

I'm using python imaplib to read Gmail messages from the [Gmail] All Mail folder.

For most accounts, the all mail folder is named "[Gmail] All Mail". However, a couple accounts have it as: "[Gmail]/&BBIEQQRP- &BD8EPgRHBEIEMA-"

It seems to be related to an account in a foreign language.

Does anyone recognize the encoding?

Is there a way to figure out which folder is the "All Mail" folder?

Alternatively, is there a systematic way of getting all the possible names of the All Mail folder so I can search for it?

Comment: As for the the character encoding, imaplib doesn't handle that (it's fairly basic). IMAPClient may be a better library (http://pypi.python.org/pypi/IMAPClient/), it handles character encodings + a lot other stuff imaplib doesn't handle. (This is probably far too late, but just so the googlers know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GMail supports an XLIST function to get the localized name of the folder.

See [Gmail IMAP Extensions](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/imap_extensions)