# Outlook folder have some unique ID?

Tags: outlook, imap

I have problem with label or folder if is not **spacial-use-mailboxes**. When I download mail I will tagging them with mailboxes name but in case user change language some label (eg. Achieve and Snoozed) it change name with user selected. And older mail I downloaded before it can't tag with new language anymore and new mail in this mailboxes have new tagging with label in new language. In **spacial-use-mailboxes** case I will tagging with standard attribute.

Other folder in outlook have something like ID or unique some field to using to identify is same folder but different language?

Comment: The problem you have found is precisely what special-use solves, and why it was defined. Lack of support is a pain.

Comment: Do you mean the "Archive" Exchange folder? Or your own folders that you create?

Comment: @arnt Gmail haven't found problem like this. But outlook spacial-use not covered all of default mailboxes

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko It default mailboxes of outlook. When I change language name of mailboxes change name too.

Comment: Gmail haven't found? Several people have asked about gmail, typically about cross-acount matching. [Here is a random example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12361055/fnord).

Comment: @arnt In library I using to fetch mailboxes gmail have attributes (spacial-use) all of default mailboxes. Then I can check this is same default mailboxes in different language.